# jQuery collapseable div inside ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have some divs in my ASP.NET page that live inside of an update panel which collapse and expand when a user clicks on them.  From Googleing around, I've got it wired up so that the expanding and collapsing on click works okay inside the update panel...like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a.groupBtn").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().next(".device-list").slideToggle("fast");
            });
        });

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
            $("a.groupBtn").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().next(".device-list").slideToggle("fast");
            });
        });
```

This all works okay, but the problem I'm having is every time the Update Panel ticks, the divs return to their default state, which is collapsed.  Is there any way to wire this up so that the divs will remember their state whenever the update panel ticks?

EDIT:  Here is my page.  The divs are programatically generated inside of UpdatePanel3.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="DashboardFrontEnd.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("a.groupBtn").click(function () {
                 $(this).parent().next(".device-list").slideToggle("fast");
                 var $hState = $(".div-state");
                 var val = ($hState.val() || 0) == 1;
                 $hState.val(!val);
                });
            });


         var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
         prm.add_endRequest(function () {
             var $hState = $(".div-state");
             var val = $hState.val() == 1;
             if (val)
                 $(this).parent().next(".device-list").show()
             else
                 $(this).parent().next(".device-list").hide();
        });
</script>


<div class="topBar">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/summit-logo-website.png" />
        <div id="stack-title">Network Monitor Dashboard</div>
        <hr />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="redPnl" runat="server" CssClass="panel red" Visible="False" Direction="LeftToRight"></asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="5000">
                    </asp:Timer>
                </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <br />

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="yellowPnl" runat="server" BackColor="#FFCC00" CssClass="panel" Visible="False"></asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <br />

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <input runat="server" class="div-state" />
            <div id="device-list">
                <asp:Panel ID="greenPnl" runat="server" CssClass="panel">
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Direction="RightToLeft" CssClass="right device-detail" Visible="False">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:Panel>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>




    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the update panel tick re-render the entire page?

Comment: No, just the content inside the update panel, which happens to be my divs

Comment: There is probably many ways to solve this issue. The quick and dirty is to store the state in DOM elements outside the panel. And how about using to-way binding with another JS-framework, for example Knockoutjs? If you two-way bind the state, it will save the state until you reload the JavaScript file

Comment: Is it possible to give the `div`'s the attribute `runat="server"` so that their state information is sent to the server on the AJAX postback and saved?

Answer (score 0):

I can use HiddenField (outside UpdatePanel) for stored the state of the DIV and manage the event [endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383810(v=vs.100).aspx) for asyc request. 
Put the hidden field in the container of the UpdatePanel

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="DashboardFrontEnd.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $("a.groupBtn").click(function () {
                 $(this).parent().next(".device-list").slideToggle("fast");
                 var $hState = $(".div-state");
                 var val = ($hState.val() || 0) == 1;
                 $hState.val(!val);
                });
            });


         var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
         prm.add_endRequest(function () {
             var $hState = $(".div-state");
             var val = $hState.val() == 1;
             if (val)
                 $(this).parent().next(".device-list").show()
             else
                 $(this).parent().next(".device-list").hide();
        });
</script>


<div class="topBar">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="img/summit-logo-website.png" />
        <div id="stack-title">Network Monitor Dashboard</div>
        <hr />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="redPnl" runat="server" CssClass="panel red" Visible="False" Direction="LeftToRight"></asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="5000">
                    </asp:Timer>
                </ContentTemplate>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <br />

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="yellowPnl" runat="server" BackColor="#FFCC00" CssClass="panel" Visible="False"></asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <br />
            <input runat="server" class="div-state" />
             <!-- THE HIDDEN FIELD MUST BE OUTSIDE THE UPDATE PANEL -->
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
               
            <div id="device-list">
                <asp:Panel ID="greenPnl" runat="server" CssClass="panel">
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Direction="RightToLeft" CssClass="right device-detail" Visible="False">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:Panel>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>




    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You're above my head though as I'm by no means a jQuery expert.  Where would I put this code and what kind of code do I need to use to Restore Prev State?

Comment: Fabio, I tried your code and the divs expand initially like they are supposed to and then collapse by themselves when the update panel ticks, then its like the expand functionality dies..no matter how many times I click on them, they will not expand again.  Do you have any more ideas on how I can get this working?

Comment: Can you post your page?

Comment: I've edited my original post to show my page.  Let me know if you want to see the CSS or the code-behind.

Comment: Ok, the the hidden field must be outside the updatepanel else you lost the state when the updatepanel comes refreshed

Comment: Ok, I made the correction as you suggested, but it still doesn't work.  I'm thinking its because the divs are being re-created every time the update panel updates.  Thoughts?

Comment: The problem is as you said that for any reason the hidden field is create each time,  Do you try to use firebug or another developer bar? Do you have a full postback?

Comment: Yes, I've used Firebug to look at the page.  The update panels are the only thing refreshing, not the entire page.  My previous comment was referring to divs inside the update panel.  I'm wondering if the fact that they are being recreated each tick is contributing to the problem.  I've double checked the hidden input field and it does not appear to be being recreated each tick, so I don't think that's the issue, but i'm not sure.

Comment: The selector '.device-list' is wrong because device-list is a id not a css class. Change '.device-list' with '#device-list'. Where's   the groupBtn in your code?

Comment: I had both a class and an ID name '.device-list'.  I renamed the ID appropriately so the class '.device-list' is still there.  That doesn't seem to be the issue, though, as the divs auto collapse on the first tick of the timer.

groupBtn is being generated in the code behind after a LINQ query.  That all works fine, like everything else, until the Update Panel updates itself.

Thanks for the help so far.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What kind is groupBtn? Is It a LinkButton? Can you make an example with button in page insert in page statically?